# Defining master slide format for Slidy slides generated with Pandoc

Tags: pandoc, slidy

I'm generating Slidy presentations using Pandoc and I'd like to add images to the left and right bottom corners of every slide. What is the best way to define the appearance of the background for each slide?

Answer (score 2):

Execute `pandoc -D slidy > mytemplate.slidy` to get [pandoc's default template](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#templates) for slidy and save it in a file. Modify it to your tastes and then use it with `pandoc --template mytemplate.slidy`